# How do I use Harpy Traps?

Tags: the-witcher-2

I'm trying to complete The Harpy Contract outside of Vergen, and while I've slain enough harpies that the quest has updated to "use harpy traps! 0/7 nests", I don't know what I'm supposed to be *doing* with said harpy traps.

How do I take out Harpy Nests?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To destroy their nest, you need to use harpy traps that you need to craft.

Some of the dwarf blacksmiths sells the diagram: Haggard, the blacksmith's apprentice,  and Earso. Thorak also sell the traps themselves so you don't have to waste the precious silver ore.

You will find the harpies at the quarry.

Set the traps on the ground and lure them over. They'll pick up the trap and fly it to their nest. This grants 4/7 progress.

Continue with the main quest (Hunting Magic). You will find the rest in the harpy caves, which is hard to miss.

Comment: While it seems obvious, I'd rather be sure before I waste precious silver ore.  How many total traps must be crafted in total?  I assume 7 - one per nest?

Comment: @Guhndahb - yes, one per nest.